# Python fast Kernel Density estimation (probability density function)

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm looking for a way to get the kernel density function of a data set and plot it for arbitrary data points. Using Scipy stats module, I came up with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

def get_pdf(data):
    a = np.array(data)
    ag = st.gaussian_kde(a)
    x = np.linspace(0, max(data), max(data)*10)
    y = ag(x)
    return x, y
```

This gives the expected result, but the performance is very poor, when the data set size is large.

I found [`fastkde`](https://pypi.org/project/fastkde/) as an implementation for fast kernel density estimation. But I could not figure out a way to use this in the same way I used Scipy stats KDE.

Can someone give me some insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for something like this:

```py
from fastkde.fastKDE import pdf


def get_pdf(data):
    y, x = pdf(data)
    return x, y
```

Note that, in general, `fastKDE.pdf()` returns `pdf, axes` (the PDF and the axes of the PDF, analogous to `hist, bins` for a histogram).

If there are multiple input variables, the `axes` variable is a list of the axes, with each axis corresponding to an input variable.

Comment: I have a related question about `fastkde` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78126259/how-to-use-python-package-fastkde-to-predict-density-at-each-given-data-point). Could you please have a check on my question?